# ForAppending not working with CreateTextFile - VBA

Tags: vba, logging

I have this:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHappened
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "Log.txt", ForAppending, True)
oFile.WriteLine eLogMessage
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

Appending is not working.  Does anyone know why this always overwrites whats in the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is creating a new file each time it is run. That's because you're using ".CreateTextFile". Hense, no appending of a currently existing file. So, we need to check if the file exists. If it does not exist, we'll create a new file. If it already exists, we'll append the existing file.

This sample assumes a folder in the root of the "C:" drive with the name "test". The code below works and can be modified for your purposes. The first time the code is run, it creates a new file and writes to it. After the file is created, it will then append the existing file.

```
Sub WriteSample()
Dim fso As Object
Dim f As Object
Const ForAppending = 8
Const TristateFalse = 0

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not (fso.FileExists("C:\test\testfile.txt")) Then
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test\testfile.txt", ForAppending, TristateFalse)
    f.Write "Hello World!" & vbCrLf
    f.Close

Else
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\test\testfile.txt", ForAppending, TristateFalse)
    f.Write "Hello World Again!" & vbCrLf
    f.Close

End If
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CreateTextFile(..., ForAppending, True)` you could use `OpenTextFile(..., ForAppending, True)`, where `True` means "create if not exists". See [opentextfile-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method).